# How to prevent the form from automatically moving to positive Y?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, windows-7

When I drag the Form (*with the mouse at the title bar*) to a negative Y position, Windows moves it back to `Y = 0`. How can I **prevent** that ? I'm working on Windows 7 (Windows XP didn't have that "feature").

```
// in Form1
protected override void OnMove(EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Location.ToString());
    base.OnMove(e);
}
```

---

***Why:** I work on a production software. The screen will be very low on resolution so I need to save space. I want the user to be able to move windows **anywhere**.*

Comment: I suppose it is not the default behavior. Can you confirm this and share a reproducible code ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Try it with the Windows Text-Editor. Doesn't the window move back to `Y = 0` ? And Win XP didn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

That is a standard behavior. If users push the title bar of the form off the screen, how do you expect them to pull it back?

Comment: I want to **prevent** that.

Comment: @Edit: I guess you misunderstood the question. Please read it again carefully.

Comment: My bad. Removed other details.

Comment: That _might_ be another problem **then** (but I think it would be easier to solve than this one).

Comment: Your whole approach in flawed IMHO. If space if the concern, think of UI redesign. You can make use of wizard like UI or tab control to make screens smaller. Also, user can resize the window and minimize it, right?

Comment: No. Think of a GUI that displays a camera's live image. Screen resolution is low and the `image height = screen height`. The GUI has no title bar (no minimize box) though it can be moved by dragging the client space etc. It's all working fine so far. But the window jumps back into view when you want to move it away.